# Rails - new User builds dependent Email and validates both?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I'm building a quick Rails project that allows users to manage their email addresses. Users can have many emails, but one (and only one) of those emails has to be marked as 'primary' (for login), and a user cannot exist without a primary email.

I've been struggling to get this to work right - it seems so circular to me. I need to build a User, and then the Email, but I don't want to save the User into the database unless the Email is valid, which it won't be until the User is saved (because of the `validates :user, presence: true` constraint).

Accepts nested resources for doesn't seem to work with `.new` (works fine with `.create`), and if my Email fails its validations, the User still shows as valid.

Been having a difficult time trying to find good resources (or SO questions) for building/validating multiple/dependent models from a single form.

What's the most Rails way to do this?

#### User

```
has_many :emails
has_one :primary_email, -> { where(primary: true) }, class_name: "Email"

accepts_nested_attributes_for :primary_email

validates :first_name, presence: true
validates :last_name, presence: true
validates :birthday, presence: true
validates :password_digest, presence: true
```

#### Email

```
belongs_to :user

validates :user, presence: true
validates :address, presence: true, uniqueness: {
  case_sensitive: false
}
```

#### UsersController

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    # do something
  else
    # show @user.errors
  end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :first_name,
    :last_name,
    :birthday,
    :password,
    :password_confirmation,
    :primary_email_attributes => [:address]
  )
end
```

#### EDIT

The Email model also contains the following fields:

- label = string, eg. 'Personal', 'Work', etc
- primary = boolean, whether it's marked as primary email or not
- confirmation_code = autogenerated on creation, used to confirm ownership
- confirmed = boolean, whether it's been confirmed or not

Comment: How about some Feedback for the answers you received?

Comment: Apologies - I couldn't be back on computer until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meant to post this months ago.

The solution, keeping users and emails normalized across different models without storing a primary email as an attribute on the user, is to use `inverse_of`:

#### User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails
  validates :emails, presence: true
end
```

#### Email.rb

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :emails
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

This allows validations to be performed using in-memory objects, rather than via database calls (ie the object associations are being validated, rather than the presence of an id/record in the database). Therefore they both pass validation and can both be saved in the same transaction.

See: https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
  user has_many :emails
  user has_one :primary_email, -> { where(primary: true) }, class_name: "Email", autosave: true

  after_initialize {
     build_primary_email if new_record?
  }
end


class Email
    # use gem https://github.com/balexand/email_validator
    validates :my_email_attribute, :email => true
end
```

So after a user initialized its building a primary_email so that record is already associated, or at least it will be if it can be saved. the autosave is working pretty cool - if the primary-email can't be saved due validation error, the user can't neither. should work out of the box, im in a bus right now, can't check it. cheers

futher information: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

**If validations for any of the associations fail, their error messages will be applied to the parent.** That means, the Parent Model (in your case User) is having errors, and thats why the saving is not possible! that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I had not actually seen the Autosave Association before.. I'll try working this out right now. The docs line, `When the :autosave option is not present then new association records are saved but the updated association records are not saved.` is leading me to think that it's already trying to autosave on new ones, but i'll try this out

Comment: Also, thanks for linking to the email validator gem!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue as yesterday - new Users build new primary Emails, but I can't save the User because the associated Email object doesn't have a User linked to it, which then fails the presence constraint for users. It works if I do `new_user.primary_email.user = new_user` and `new_user.save` because Emails check for presence of a user rather than user_id (which doesn't exist yet), but that seems Bad.

Comment: Should I remove the `validates :user, presence: true` in my Email model? I thought we should always have presence validations to prevent bad data from potentially entering database.

Comment: it really depends. actually i would give the user one email (primary) in  the user model and just some has_many other_emails. that is the easiest and most stable approach

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'm still trying to learn best practices for normalizing user data. What's the etiquette for accepting answers to this question? Despite yours being awesome, do I accept chumakoff's, since it's along the same lines as your comment to just store primary on User?

Comment: go with autosave or go with one fixed email at the user. that is best practice. 
if all emails are external you also need to make sure that there is always a email, always a primary email, which cant be deleted, whatever

Answer (score 1):

I would store a primary email as a common field and additional emails some another way. I would prefer to store additional emails in another field too that is Array rather than in an associated table. You shouldn't store a primary email in another table. Just imagine, every time you need authorize user or just get his email you will perform an extra request to db.

Comment: My original thinking had been that storing primary email on the User and additional emails elsewhere would result in a more complicated process to switch which email is primary - that the field is updated on the User, the now-primary email's original Email record is deleted, and a new Email model is made for the former primary one, versus just changing the primary boolean field.

Comment: The other thought was that I have other data to keep track of with the emails - I just updated the question to reflect those fields. With this other information in mind, the only two options seem to be (1) separate models, like I'm doing, or (2) an array of hstores. Am I missing an option? Is the array of hstores a better approach?